# Using RDKAFKA Assign Multiple group id to multiple consumer

Tags: php, apache-kafka

I have used RDKAFKA in php to implement running consumer parallely.

But first consumer consumed all the message from the topic so second consumer didn't get message of topic.

So i used different group id to different consumer still same issue is coming.

Please help me.
      `$`conf->set('group.id', 'myConsumerGroup');
      `$`conf->set('metadata.broker.list', '127.0.0.2');
      `$`topicConf = new RdKafka\TopicConf();
      `$`topicConf->set('auto.offset.reset', 'smallest');
      `$`conf->setDefaultTopicConf(`$`topicConf);
      `$`consumer1 = new RdKafka\KafkaConsumer(`$`conf);
      `$`consumer1->subscribe(['dbtest']);
       while (true) {
    `$`j= 0;
`$`message = `$`consumer1->consume(120*1000);

switch (`$`message->err) {
    case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR:
        `$`dataEx = json_decode(`$`message->payload,true);
        var_dump(`$`data);
        `$`sql = "INSERT INTO emp (name, email) VALUES ('".`$`dataEx['name']."','".`$`dataEx['email']."')";

```
    `$`servername = "localhost";
    `$`username = "A";
    `$`password = "ASD";
    `$`dbname = "test";
    `$`conn = new mysqli(`$`servername, `$`username, `$`password, `$`dbname);
    if (`$`conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . `$`conn->connect_error);
    }

    if (`$`conn->query(`$`sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully to datbase ".`$`dbname."/n";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . `$`sql . "<br>" . `$`conn->error;
    }
    `$`conn->close();
    echo "produced `$`j----------------------<br> ";
    break;
case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__PARTITION_EOF:
    echo "No more messages; will wait for more\n";
    break;
case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__TIMED_OUT:
    echo "Timed out\n";
    break;
default:
    throw new \Exception(`$`message->errstr(), `$`message->err);
    break;
}
$j++;
```

}
echo "here";
`$`conf->set('group.id', 'myConsumerGroup1');
`$`conf->set('metadata.broker.list', '127.0.0.2');
`$`topicConf = new RdKafka\TopicConf();
`$`topicConf->set('auto.offset.reset', 'smallest');
`$`conf->setDefaultTopicConf(`$`topicConf);

`$`consumer2 = new RdKafka\KafkaConsumer(`$`conf);
echo "sonali";
`$`consumer2->subscribe(['dbtest']);
while (true) {
`$`message2 = `$`consumer2->consume(120*1000);
switch (`$`message2->err) {
    case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR_NO_ERROR:
        `$`dataEx = json_decode(`$`message2->payload,true);
        ``$sql = "INSERT INTO emp (name, email) VALUES ('".$dataEx['name']."','".`$`dataEx['email']."')";
        $servername1 = "localhost";
        $username1 = "A";
        $password1 = "ASD";
        $dbname1 = "test1";
        `$`conn1 = new mysqli(`$`servername1, `$`username1, `$`password1, `$`dbname1);
        if (`$`conn1->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . `$`conn1->connect_error);
        }

```
    if (`$`conn1->query(`$`sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully ".`$`dbname1;
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . `$`sql . "<br>" . `$`conn1->error;
    }
    `$`conn1->close();
    echo "produced `$`j----------------------<br> ";
    break;
case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__PARTITION_EOF:
    echo "No more messages; will wait for more\n";
    break;
case RD_KAFKA_RESP_ERR__TIMED_OUT:
    echo "Timed out\n";
    break;
default:
    throw new \Exception(`$`message->errstr(), `$`message->err);
    break;
}
`$`j++;
```

}

Comment: need code for th esame

Comment: try to add the code of what you have tried so far in your questions. it will help people to help you.

Comment: Changed formatting.

Comment: Please add code used here.